# python 2.7 ImportError: No module named mock

Tags: python-2.7, python-import

I am getting error **No module named mock**. I have tried ***pip install mock*** but didn't help and I checked http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/default/Lib/unittest/mock.py and run it and it has error .. I don't know what to do with it.
How can I make it work?

version Python 2.7

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The error isn't about importing `mock`, it's about importing `apriori`. You can install it by running `pip install apriori`.